# Spring Java how to use controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm completely new to Spring framework. and I have a task to make phone book application on spring. I need to make registration and authorization and also my phone book. I have 2 controllers for that, first UserController that controls authorization and registration

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;
@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm")
                                       User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getConfirmPassword());

    return "redirect:/welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if(error!=null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Username or password is incorrect.");
    }

    if (logout!=null) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "logged out successfully");
    }

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String welcome(Model model) {
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String admin(Model model) {
    return "admin";
}
}
```

and ContactController that controls my fuctionality(adding, removing, editing and shows contacts)

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

private ContactService contactService;

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "contactService")
public void setContactService(ContactService contactService) {
    this.contactService = contactService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"admin", "welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listContactsForAdmin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
    model.addAttribute("listContacts", this.contactService.listContacts());
    return "admin";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact) {
    if (contact.getId() == 0) {
        this.contactService.addContact(contact);
    } else {
        this.contactService.updateContact(contact);
    }
    return "redirect:/admin";
}

@RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
public String removeContact(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    this.contactService.removeContact(id);

    return "redirect:/admin";
}

@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editBook(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contact", this.contactService.getContactById(id));
    model.addAttribute("listContacts", this.contactService.listContacts());

    return "admin";
}

@RequestMapping("contactData/{id}")
public String contactData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contact", this.contactService.getContactById(id));

    return "contactData";
}
```

}

when i try to authenticate or registr. new user I have such error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8087/admin': {public java.lang.String kz.adilka.springsecurity.app.controller.UserController.admin(org.springframework.ui.Model), public java.lang.String kz.adilka.springsecurity.app.controller.ContactController.listContactsForAdmin(org.springframework.ui.Model)}

it says that I have problem with mapping admin page. but for me it seems to be ok, or maybe I missed smth

Comment: The message you've got is pretty clear about the reason why exception was thrown. You have two methods mapped on the same path and Spring is not able to figure out to which of them request should be forwarded from `DispatcherServlet`. Both are eligible to process it.

Comment: @Adil why accept and then cancel it?

Comment: @lucumt sry misclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you do not set the controller value for your controllers and they have the same `RequestMapping` method

```
@Controller // do not have identifier here
public class UserController {
      @Autowired
      private UserService userService;
      @Autowired
      private SecurityService securityService;
      @Autowired
      private UserValidator userValidator;


     @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String admin(Model model) {
       return "admin";
     }
}


@Controller // do not have identifier here
public class ContactController {

  private ContactService contactService;

  @RequestMapping(value = {"admin", "welcome"}, 
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String listContactsForAdmin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
    model.addAttribute("listContacts", 
    this.contactService.listContacts());
    return "admin";
  }

}
```

One possible solution is the set `RequestMapping` for each Controller method:

```
   @Controller(value = "user")
   public class UserController {
   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;
   @Autowired
   private SecurityService securityService;
   @Autowired
   private UserValidator userValidator;


   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String admin(Model model) {
      return "admin";
   }
}


@Controller(value = "contact")
public class ContactController {

private ContactService contactService;

@RequestMapping(value = {"admin", "welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listContactsForAdmin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
    model.addAttribute("listContacts", this.contactService.listContacts());
    return "admin";
}

}
```